# How to show item in tableView of array which is inside another array in swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview, struct

This is the model I created :

```
struct Friends: Codable{
var name:String
var position:String
var details:[Detail]
}
struct Detail: Codable{
var detail:String
}
```

I want to detail in table View. How can I do it?

```
var data = [Friends]()
```

TableView is :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let data = data[indexPath.row]
    let dataDetail = data.dataDetail[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(dataDetail)"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You don’t have a dataDetail property in your Friends struct and also explain what output you expect in textLabel if what you want is the content of the details property

Comment: Title of the issue is confusing, while the description is not sufficient. Please update both. Do you want to open `Detail` cells while user tap of `Friend `cell?

Answer (score 0):

```
 plz try this code
  
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
     let dta = data[indexPath.row]
         cell.textLabel?.text = dta.details[indexPath.row].detail
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to display all values in the `details` array you can [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) the `Detail` instances to their `detail` values and [`join`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641243-joined) the string array to a single comma separated string

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let item = data[indexPath.row]        
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.details.map{$0.datail}.joined(separator: ", ")
    return cell
}
```